# Mac OS X 10 ssh timeout to linux server port 77

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

My Mac is not able to connect to a remote server, the server ssh port is 77 and if I do the command:

```
ssh -v -p77 rofer117@remoteserver.com.br
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remoteserver.com.br [177.69.70.65] port 77.
```

It won't connect, but if I connect to another remote server with port 22 or 2222 it will allow me to connect.

I think that is something related with the firewall, but the same is turned off...

Appreciate any help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What happens if you do: `telnet remoteserver.com.br 77`?

Comment: telnet remoteserver.com.br 77
Trying 100.69.70.00...
telnet: connect to address 100.69.70.00: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: If I connect using windows with putty, it will work.

Comment: I notice that the problem is with amazon aws, my instances are not been showed at the main panel, maybe a problem with them...

Comment: Are you absolutely (bet your hat|life|wife on it certain) that you've configured your AWS Security group to allow TCP connections to port 77?